# How can I fix not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)?

Tags: django, django-views, sendmail, django-mailer

My goal is to send contact form information in my Gmail when a user will submit the contact form. I tried different ways, but couldn't solve it. What's wrong here? Please give me a relevant solution...

***setting.py:***

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'demo@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'vkqhtdnqhzfrcuhs'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

***views.py:***

```
def ContactME(request):

    

    if request.method == "POST":
        MessageSenderName = request.POST.get('name'),
        SenderEmail = request.POST.get('email'),
        SenderMessage = request.POST.get('message'),
        Contact.objects.create(
            Name = MessageSenderName,
            Email = SenderEmail,
            Message = SenderMessage,
        )

       
        send_mail(
            MessageSenderName,
            SenderMessage,
            SenderEmail,
            ['demo@gmail.com'],
        )
```

***error:***

```
ValueError at /ContactME
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ContactME
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
Exception Location: D:\1_WebDevelopment\0-Portfolio\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py, line 99, in sanitize_address
Raised during:  portfolioApp.views.ContactME
Python Executable:  D:\1_WebDevelopment\0-Portfolio\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\0-Portfolio',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\0-Portfolio\\venv',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\0-Portfolio\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 23 Aug 2022 17:00:59 +0000
```

Comment: Remove the trailing commas in `request.POST.get('name'),` etc...

Comment: thnk you it solved

Comment: But I faced another issue is, the sender mail and receiver mail show the same.